# How to remove unwanted top-level packages in setup.cfg?

Tags: python, setuptools

I'm working on a `setup.cfg` for my first Python package following [this guide](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/#creating-the-package-files). It mostly works, but the problem is it includes subfolders of my package as top-level packages. Source tree:

```
setup.cfg
src
  Accentizer2
    __init__.py
    Accentizer.py
    Annotation.py
    DawgSharp
      YaleDawg.py
    Russian
      Stress.py
      Syllable.py
      Vowels.py
```

(I know, the capitalisation is non-conventional. I'm fixing that soon.)

setup.cfg:

```
[options]
package_dir =
    = src
packages = find:

[options.packages.find]
where = src
exclude =
    Accentizer2/DawgSharp
    Accentizer2/Russian
```

Here is partial output of `py -m build`:

```
adding 'Accentizer2/Accentizer.py'
adding 'Accentizer2/Annotation.py'
adding 'Accentizer2/__init__.py'
adding 'Accentizer2/DawgSharp/YaleDawg.py'
adding 'Accentizer2/DawgSharp/__init__.py'
adding 'Accentizer2/Russian/Stress.py'
adding 'Accentizer2/Russian/Syllable.py'
adding 'Accentizer2/Russian/Vowels.py'
adding 'Accentizer2/Russian/__init__.py'
adding 'DawgSharp/YaleDawg.py'
adding 'DawgSharp/__init__.py'
adding 'Russian/Stress.py'
adding 'Russian/Syllable.py'
adding 'Russian/Vowels.py'
adding 'Russian/__init__.py'
```

As you can see, it's adding `DawgSharp` and `Russian` twice: inside Accentizer2 and at the top level. Why? It's also adding `DawgSharp/__init__.py` and `Russian/__init__.py` which are not part of the src tree.

How do I change my `setup.cfg` so that the resulting package only contains `DawgSharp` and `Russian` as subfolders and not top-level modules? They are implementation details which the users of my package should not worry about.

Answer (score 1):

I just needed to clean my build folder. It was picking up old versions of the files (before they were moved).